# iOS build size is too large how can i upload ipa?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have finally ready to upload my App to the App store, but my build size is too large.

Anyone has an idea to solve this problem to upload my application. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make your app smaller

Comment: i m not now able to my app smaller because my app is relate to some Static video and some animation which i have done @Lu_

Comment: rather than having static content, make user download it after installing.

Comment: static content mean some videos which related for some use @Mr.Bista

Comment: I understand, but you can make it to download automatically when user download, installs and opens the app for the first time. By this way the size will reduce for the app store and the static content will be downloaded after app install. And if you want to keep static content is build itself, then look for some compression techniques.

Comment: use on demand resource